# Regex only returning first part of match

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract `the cat` and `another mat` from this sentence:

```
>>> text = "the cat sat on another mat"
>>> 
>>> re.findall('(the|another)\s+\w+', text)
['the', 'another']
```

But it won't return the `cat` and `mat` following. If I change it to `re.findall('another\s+\w+', text)` then it finds that part, but why doesn't the `(first thing | second thing)` work?

(Using Python's `re` module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do

```
import re
text = "the cat sat on another mat"

re.findall('the\s+\w+|another\s+\w+', text)
```

The result should be

```
>>> ['the cat', 'another mat']
```

Comment: How does the "greedy"ness of regex have anything to do with the OP's problem?

Comment: But "lazy" in regex is simply the opposite of "greedy", both of which have nothing to do with the OP's problem. Besides, most regular expressions are actually "greedy", not "lazy".

Comment: Ok thanks for the correction. I removed the statement. I will recheck the use of lazy and greedy in regex. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, this solution requires a repetition of `\s+\w+` for each word the OP wants to test, so if there are 10 more words to be included in the regex, you would have to repeat `\s+\w+` 10 more times. This is exactly where groups should be used.

Comment: I agree. My aim was to make the solution as clear as possible to every user. Thanks for that great comment.

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall` returns only the substrings in the capture group if a capture group exists in the given regex pattern, so in this case you should use a non-capturing group instead, so that `re.findall` would return the entire matches:

```
re.findall('(?:the|another)\s+\w+', text)
```

This returns:

```
['the cat', 'another mat']
```